# Python: use a function in pandas lambda expression

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe

I have the following code, trying to find the hour of the 'Dates' column in a data frame:

```
print(df['Dates'].head(3))
df['hour'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_hour(x['Dates']), axis=1)

def find_hour(self, input):
    return input[11:13].astype(float)
```

where the `print(df['Dates'].head(3))` looks like:

```
0    2015-05-13 23:53:00
1    2015-05-13 23:53:00
2    2015-05-13 23:33:00
```

However, I got the following error:

```
    df['hour'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_hour(x['Dates']), axis=1)
NameError: ("global name 'find_hour' is not defined", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Does anyone know what I missed? Thanks!

---

Note that if I put the function directly in the lambda line like below, everything works fine:

```
df['hour'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Dates'][11:13], axis=1).astype(float)
```

Comment: You can also extract the hour directly from x if it is a datetime object and what is self supposed to be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to use `find_hour` before it has yet been defined.  You just need to switch things around:

```
def find_hour(self, input):
    return input[11:13].astype(float)

print(df['Dates'].head(3))
df['hour'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_hour(x['Dates']), axis=1)
```

**Edit**: Padraic has pointed out a very important point: `find_hour()` is defined as taking two arguments, `self` and `input`, but you are giving it only one.  You should define `find_hour()` as `def find_hour(input):` except that defining the argument as `input` shadows the built-in function.  You might consider renaming it to something a little more descriptive.

Answer (score 7):

what is wrong with old good `.dt.hour`?

```
In [202]: df
Out[202]:
                 Date
0 2015-05-13 23:53:00
1 2015-05-13 23:53:00
2 2015-05-13 23:33:00

In [217]: df['hour'] = df.Date.dt.hour

In [218]: df
Out[218]:
                 Date  hour
0 2015-05-13 23:53:00    23
1 2015-05-13 23:53:00    23
2 2015-05-13 23:33:00    23
```

and if your `Date` column is of string type you may want to convert it to datetime **first**:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

or just:

```
df['hour'] = int(df.Date.str[11:13])
```